# Should [hamming] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

It seems that [hamming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamming) is used mostly for tagging questions, which are about [hamming-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamming-code) or [hamming-distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamming-distance).

What's more, there is even no wiki excerpt for this tag. Maybe because it's hard to find any other possible usage of [hamming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamming) different than [hamming-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamming-code) or [hamming-distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hamming-distance). It looks like this two tags would be just enough.

Comment: They want to take my chee... ham!

Comment: With only 30 questions tagged with hamming it should be fairly easy to retag them.

Comment: You really should have dramatized this question more somehow... you know, hammed it up.

Comment: There's also a Hamming window (not to be confused with the Hanning window)

Comment: Stop ... hamming time!